# How to limit the answers of the GROUP BY clause in sql-server (2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, limit

I'm trying to get the top 50 cities for all customer lists in our DB
(So simplified: every client has a list of customers with associated data(like the city))

If I say:

```
 SELECT top(50) clientid, city, COUNT(city) as cnt
 FROM customers
 GROUP BY clientid, city
 ORDER by cnt
```

it will limit the total resultset on 50 rows instead of limiting the results for every group.

How can I get the top 50 per clientid?

EDIT:
I searched stackoverflow (and googled) but only found solutions for Mysql. Probably searching for 'limit' will only find mysql solutions wince thats the keyword needed for that Database engine. If I know the keyword needed in Sql-Server I could find it as well using google.

Comment: what do you mean by "top 50" exactly? What's the criteria for ranking?

Comment: @ramy: With 'top 50' I mean ordered by the occurence count of the city. So the more users live in a city, the higher they rank

Comment: how do the answers below look to you, @Dirk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH cte
     As (SELECT clientid,
                city,
                COUNT(city) as cnt,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientid 
                                       ORDER BY COUNT(city)) AS RN
         FROM   customers
         GROUP  BY clientid,
                   city)
SELECT clientid,
       city
FROM   cte
WHERE  RN <= 50
```

Comment: It looks like it is working. Could you give a small explanation on the logic behind the query?

Comment: @Dirk - This is just a "Greatest n per group" query. There is some explanation here http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/More-SQL-Server-2005-Solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it:

```
select top 50 city
from (select city from customers group by city order by count(clientid) desc)
```

I assume if a clientID is in the same row as a city, then that clientID represents a user living in that city.

Comment: your query doesn't seem to work. It doesn't group the cities by client (so top cities for every client (which owns its customers))